# How to toggle the console with a button in a GUI program

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, pysimplegui

When I run my program (.exe file), the console automatically turns on.
I don't want to get rid of it, but I want to have the ability to hide it.
I know that I can completely get rid of the console while coverting .py to .exe with the auto-py-to-exe module.

Is there a way to turn the console on and off with a button, without closing the program or anything like that?
I am using the PySimpleGui Library for the gui if that changes anything.

The Button:

[image: Console toggle button]

Comment: you want to turn on/off a new console? Or the one that starts up when you launch a `.py` ?

Comment: I could have specified that I compressed the program to exe, and the console is automatically on.

Comment: and do you want to toggle it? or just get rid of it

Comment: Why does your GUI program even have a console? Perhaps you converted it into an .exe incorrectly.

Comment: I could have also specified that, yes I want to toggle it. I know you can turn off the console completely while converting .py to .exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use pywin32 library to hide/show the console, and it work only for WINDOWS.

```py
import win32gui, win32con
import PySimpleGUI as sg

console = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

layout = [[sg.Button( "Console ON/OFF", key="-CONSOLE-")]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

view_console = True
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "-CONSOLE-":
        view_console = not view_console
        option = win32con.SW_SHOW if view_console else win32con.SW_HIDE
        win32gui.ShowWindow(console, option)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Altho I don't thing that with all of my librarys, my program would work on different operating system, would be nice to find a way to do it on every os.

Comment: Know nothing about Linux and MacOS, so that's all.